# Spring does not complain if a property is not set when using ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, configurationproperties

I have a bean that is configured via ConfigurationProperties:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mybean")
public class MyBean {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    // Getters, setters, ...
}
```

I configure the field values via `application.yml` but in "two levels". In the default application.yml I just set the value *to the value of another property*:

```
myBean.name: ${theValueOf.myBean.name}
```

In the profile specific YML file I have:

```
theValueOf.myBean.name: 'The desired value'
```

My expectation would be that if I forget to specify the property `theValueOf.myBean.name` then the application should fail at startup with the message that the placeholder 'theValueOf.myBean.name' could not be resolved. Instead, the field `name` is assigned the value (literally) `${theValueOf.myBean.name}`.

If I annotate the `name` field with `@Value("${myBean.name}")` (and do not use ConfigurationProperties), and forget to define the property `theValueOf.myBean.name`, then the application fails at startup -- as expected.

**My question is**: How can I make Spring fail at startup with the message 'Could not resolve placeholder ...' when using ConfigurationProperties?

Answer (score 0):

Simply mark your properties with JSR303 annotations, inside your @ConfigurationProperties.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mybean")
public class MyBean {

   @NotEmpty
   private String name;
}
```

Comment: Err... You are right! I forgot to mention that I alraedy annotated the field with `@NotEmpty`. But, as I said, the field is assigned the value "${...}" which is not empty, and hence there is no complaint. I updated the code example in the original question.